# SpriteKit - Struct for nodes position

Tags: swift, struct, sprite-kit, skscene

i want to make a struct where i declare different positions. I have many nodes which always use the same positions so instead of typing every time the same x-values and y-values i would like to just type positions.p1.

```
private struct Positions {
    let P1 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.05
    let P2 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.15
}
```

Now i get the error: `Instance member frame cannot be used on type myGameScene.` myGameScene is a SKScene.

If i try self. instead of myGameScene i get the error: `Value of type NSObject -> () -> myGameScene has no member frame.`

Need help :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work

```
class MyGameScene: SKScene { }

let myGameScene = MyGameScene()

struct XPositions {
    let x0 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.05
    let x1 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.15
}

print(XPositions().x0)
```

[image]

However let me say it's a weird way to solve the problem infact:

1. You are using a struct instead of an array
2. You need to create a value of the struct just to access the properties that are the same of every value of Positions
3. The properties (P1, P2) should be lowercase...

### Suggestion

Why don't you just add a computed property to your scene?

```
class MyGameScene: SKScene {
    lazy var positions: [CGFloat] = {
        let factors: [CGFloat] = [0.15, 0.05]
        return factors.map { $0 * self.frame.size.width }
    }()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this beautiful answer. My bad, my code looked like `import SpriteKit  
  
class MyGameScene: SKScene {  
  
let myGameScene = MyGameScene()  
  
struct XPositions {  
    let x0 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.05  
    let x1 = myGameScene.frame.size.width * 0.15  
}  
}` -> so my struct was inside my game class. Im sure your computed property would solve the problem in a better way, but i don't understand this really. Lets say i would have 10 different positions for 10 different nodes, how would i use this 10 positions in `exampleNode.position = `?

Comment: @aignetti: There are 2 problems with your code. 1) You are using an instance property  before the current object has been initialised and this is not possible. 2) You created an infinite recursion because a `MyGameScene` contains another `MyGameScene` which contains another `MyGameScene`...

Comment: @aignetti: `$0` is the n-th element of `factors`. Please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html) to better undestard how map words.

Comment: thank you. i will read and try it. And thank your for your explenation. im new to swift so every tip is very helpful for me. :-)

Comment: If i want to use now positions how would it look like? `exampleNode.position.x = positions(0)` to get self.frame.size.width * 0.15?

Comment: @aignetti: Inside an instance of `MyGameScene` just write `positions[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Use bounds instead of frame.

```
private struct Positions {
     let P1 = myGameScene.bounds.size.width * 0.05
     let P2 = myGameScene.bounds.size.width * 0.15
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Same problem here with `bounds`.